# Can I keep . and .. out of .* expansion?

Tags: bash, shell, expansion, dotfiles

I often find it annoying (or worse) when I type

```
command .*
```

in bash and the command applies to the parent directory and current directory. Is there some shell option or other configuration I can tweak to make bash exclude `.` and `..` from the expansion of `.*`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In bash, in this order:

```
GLOBIGNORE=.
shopt -u dotglob
```

When GLOBIGNORE is set, . and .. are automatically ignored, so you dont actually need to set them in GLOBIGNORE, but if you have nothing else to ignore you wont have anything to set it to.

Every time you set GLOBIGNORE to a non-null value, bash turns on the option `dotglob`, so you will need to turn it off afterwards; otherwise bash will expand `*` to include files starting with a dot.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I actually would rather have `dotglob` turned on, so setting `GLOBIGNORE` sounds perfect.

Comment: When GLOBIGNORE is set, Bash does ignore `.` and `..` but not `foo/.` and `foo/..`. You may want to use `GLOBIGNORE=.:*/.:*/..` to make this work with path names too.

Answer (score 3):

On an unfamiliar system where I have too little time for checking the settings in use (like GLOBIGNORE) I use the following foolproof pattern:

```
command .??*
```

- Quick to type and guaranteed to exclude `.` and `..` regardless of the environment.

Comment: I always liked this approach, but be aware that it fails to match 1-char files `.a`