# How to mv dot files without including the parent directory on linux/mac?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I keep . and .. out of .* expansion?](https://superuser.com/questions/178633/can-i-keep-and-out-of-expansion)

I know about

```
mv * ~/whatever
mv .* ~/whatever
```

but that tries to move `.` and `..`, which just caused me a bunch of pain. Is there a way to mv all the files, including the `.*` files, but exclude the current directory and it's parent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just tell bash there is the second character and it is not a dot. Will not move files named like `..file`, though.

```
mv .[^.]* somewhere/
```

Comment: This will work in most of the cases but will ignore files and directories beginning with two dots. For example `..name` or `....name`.

Comment: @Matteo: I already mention the issue in the answer.

Comment: @chroba sorry: should learn to read the whole answer :-)

Answer (score 8):

From the Bash manual, `shopt` section:

```
dotglob     If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results
            of pathname expansion.
```

`shopt` can be used to set certain "shell options" as explained in the manual. See `man bash`.

Thus

```
shopt -s dotglob
mv * ~/whatever
```

does what you want. Test it with e.g.

```
shopt -s dotglob
ls -d *
```

to see which files are matched.

Since it is the de facto Bash way as per the manual, no hidden surprises should turn up regarding files with tricky names. If it does, it is by definition a bug in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mv .[a-zA-Z0-9]* ~/whatever
```

Unless you have dot files that start with `._` or other non-alphanumeric characters, it should get them all.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move directories, this will move all files to `./foo/`:

```
$ find . -type f  | while read n; do mv "$n" foo/; done
```

If you do need to do directories also, try:

```
$ find . | grep -vP '^\.$' | while read n; do mv "$n" foo/; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find which excludes `.` and `..`:

```
find . -name ".*" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
```

and check the result. To move the files

```
find . -name ".*" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} ~/whatever \;
```